# EntityManage - How can I Rollback 1st table updated data if 2nd table update is not successful using hibernate entitymanager

Tags: hibernate-entitymanager

I want to update two database tables using hibernate entityManager. Currently I am updating 2nd table after verifying that data has been updated in 1st table.

My question is how to Rollback 1st table if data is not updated in 2nd table.

This is how I am updating individual table.

```
try {
 wapi = getWapiUserUserAuthFlagValues(subject, UserId);
 wapi.setFlags((int) flags);
 entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
 entityManager.merge(wapi);
 entityManager.flush();
 entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (NoResultException nre) {
 wapi = new Wapi(); 
 wapi.setSubject(merchant);
 wapi.setUserId(UserId);
 wapi.setFlags((int) flags);
 entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

Note - I am calling separate methods to update each table data

Thanks

Comment: have you tried with any code??

Comment: @AjStyles Added code. This is how I am updating data in two methods. Thanks for your response

Comment: are you using maven or spring boot services to implemnt hibernate-entity ?

Comment: spring boot services

Comment: why don't you show your code for the Controller and other classes

Comment: code is confidential. So I can't. And I believe I asked my question clearly and there is no need to share whole code. If you have any idea how to do it and have any sample so please share.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution. basically I was calling two methods to update 2 db table and these two methods I am calling from one method.
Ex - I am method p and q from method r.
Initially I was calling begin, merge, flush and commit entitymanager methods in both p and q.
Now I am calling begin and commit in r and merge and flush in p and q.
So now my tables are getting updated together and rollback is also simple.

Hope it will help someone. Because I wasted my time for this, probably it can save someone else.

Thanks